# Is every type constructor (`Type -> Type`) some kind of functor

Tags: haskell, category-theory

It is well-known that a type constructor with kind `Type -> Type` (in System F-omega) is only a `Functor` if it implements a function `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b`. This is a lawless functor though, it should also adhere to the functor laws (preserve composition and identity). So a type constructor with `Type -> Type` is not always a functor. But this is only about covariant endofunctors in the category of types. There's also contravariant functors and many more kinds of functors.

My question: is any type constructor/function with kind `Type -> Type` some kind of (category-theoretic) lawful functor (covariant, contravariant, or some other kind)?

Comment: What about `data F a = F (a -> a)` ? This is neither covariant nor contravariant.

Comment: Isn't that an invariant functor: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/invariant-0.5.4/docs/Data-Functor-Invariant.html

Comment: Contravariant functors aren't really mappings `Type -> Type` but rather `Hask -> Hask⁰ᵠ` (opposite category). If you mean `Hask -> Hask` then the answer is _no_. If you do allow for other categories then the answer will certainly be _yes_ in some boring trivial sense.

Comment: If you get to choose your category, everything is a functor.

Comment: @Labbekak Quoting from your link "Any * -> * type parametric in the argument permits an instance of Invariant.". Hence, yes, it's an invariant functor but it looks like everything is. Perhaps you could rephrase the question as "is there some `F :: * -> *` which is not an invariant functor?".

Comment: Ah, I did not see that line, then the answer to my question is "yes" indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is always a functor to and from the discrete category (a category with only identity arrows) of Haskell types. It assigns to every object `a` an object `f a`. And we have automatically an arrow `f a -> f a`, namely the identity function, for every arrow (which are only identity functions) `a -> a`. The laws hold trivially since the only composition that is going on is identity arrows composed with themselves.